# Consequences Of Renaming A User Account

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, user-profile, user, user-accounts

What are the consequences in SharePoint of renaming a user account in Active Directory?  i.e. historical data, running workflows, etc.

E.g. the context is that there is a merge of domains in our organisation.  Some end-users from different domains have duplicate user names so we need to rename one of them.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can face problem as sometimes  the profile synchronization timer job does not correctly synchronize the changes in the User name and Account name information.

You need to execute the following Move-SPUser command (an equivalent of the STSADM MigrateUser command) for the user account in order to update the account name in SharePoint:

```
Move-SPUser -Identity "DOMAIN\jdoh" -NewAlias "DOMAIN\jdoe"
```

or

```
stsadm -o migrateuser -oldlogin EU\susanapi -newlogin EU\suzanapi -ignoresidhistory
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff681014.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/01/user-login-name-changed-in-ad-how-to-sync-with-sharepoint.html

[Update user profile for user whose account name has changed in AD](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26527/update-user-profile-for-user-whose-account-name-has-changed-in-ad)

Answer (score 2):

Recently I had similar but no the same issue: one user get married and changed her surname. Admins changed her Active Directory login name.

The only problem we faced was with Project Server 2013 in Project Permission Mode - I had to add user manually to Security Group.

All other permissions etc was intact.

Web app was in claims mode.

But what happens if you change not only login name but only Domain - it may be different issue.